# directives talking to controllers throws an error

Tags: angularjs

I have buttonView

```
angularModule.directive('buttonview',function(){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller : "ButtonController",
    template: '<button></button>'
}
})
```

I have given a controller to this.
 angularModule.controller("ButtonController",function($scope){

```
$scope.onButtonClick = function(){
    alert('button click...');
}

this.addAlert = function(){
    alert("alert in ButtonController..");
};
});
```

now I have created a numberButtonView that should use the buttonView s controller.

```
angularModule.directive("numberButtonview",function(){
return{
    require:"buttonview",
    link : function(scope,element,attrs,btnController){
        btnController.addAlert();
    }
}
});

<number-buttonview></number-buttonview>
```

This throws an error "Controller 'buttonview', required by directive 'numberButtonview', can't be found!"

What could be the issue here?

Comment: `buttonview` is your directive name not the controller name.

Comment: `require:"^ButtonController",` try this!

Comment: The ^ prefix means that this directive searches for the controller on its parents (without the ^ prefix, the directive would look for the controller on just its own element).

Comment: yes i tried all these. finally found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here I found the answer.number-buttonview is not the directive but it is attribute that has been created to the directive buttonview so its not the proper way to give the attribute

```
<number-buttonview></number-buttonview>
```

so correct way to give the attribute is

```
<buttonview number-buttonview></buttonview>
```